# Problema ao enviar e-mail pelo Demoiselle Mail

Tags: demoiselle

Boa tarde Pessoal,

Estou seguindo os passos para enviar e-mail pelo demoiselle mail, porém não obtive êxito. Realizei todas as configurações propostas na documentação, no console do eclipse ele diz que a mensagem foi enviada, porém não chegou e-mail algum.

Segue abaixo link da documentação:
http://demoiselle.sourceforge.net/docs/components/junit/reference/2.3.1/html/mail-master.html

Segue abaixo as implementações que fiz em um projeto de teste.

**pom.xml**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.component</groupId>
        <artifactId>demoiselle-mail</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

**demoiselle.properties**

```
# Configurações do Servidor de E-mail
frameworkdemoiselle.mail.user=riicardolara@gmail.com
frameworkdemoiselle.mail.password=minha senha
frameworkdemoiselle.mail.serverHost=smtp.gmail.com
frameworkdemoiselle.mail.serverPort=465
frameworkdemoiselle.mail.enable.ssl=true
frameworkdemoiselle.mail.auth=true
frameworkdemoiselle.mail.type=local
frameworkdemoiselle.mail.enable.tls=false
frameworkdemoiselle.mail.require.tls=false
```

**Classe de teste**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.mail.Mail;
import br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.stereotype.ViewController;

@ViewController
public class TesteView implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Inject
private Mail mail;

public void enviar() {
    mail.from("riicardolara@gmail.com")
        .to("ricardolara@djsystem.com.br")
        .body().text("Primeiro E-mail")
        .subject("Assunto")
        .importance().high().send();
}
}
```

**Na página index.jsf apenas inseri um commandButton**

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"                     
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                template="/template/main.xhtml">
 <ui:define name="body">
     <p:panel>
        <p:commandButton value="email" actionListener="#{testeView.enviar()}" />
     </p:panel>

 </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Quando inicio o servidor e tento realizar o envio do e-mail, o console do eclipse retorna que a mensagem foi enviada, porém não recebo nenhum e-mail:

```
14:39:47,595 WARN  [br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.internal.implementation.ConfigurationLoader] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Não é necessário adicionar o ponto após o prefixo para uma classe de configuração. É recomendado que sejam retirados, pois poderão causar erros em versões futuras do  Framework.
14:39:47,674 INFO  [br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.mail.internal.Dispatcher] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Preparing to send message
14:39:47,690 INFO  [br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.mail.internal.Dispatcher] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Message Sent!
```

**Segue link para download do projeto:**

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0aqa1lsskh9buod/testeEmail.7z?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na lista de usuários do projeto foi comentado sobre um dependência implícita que atrapalhava a execução. Usando como base o seu projeto fiz alguns testes, fazendo a exclusão da biblioteca. Neste link o projeto modificado: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vfhdsoveukua6ey/testeEmail.7z?dl=0

Criei um teste unitário para facilitar a execução, e com alguns provedores como yahoo e gmail funcionou. Inclusive um interno aqui no SERPRO que é o Expresso. Há casos onde há firewall ou proxy que podem impedir a comunicação. Mas deve ocorrer erro nestes casos.

Essa questão da dependência é um bug do componente. Caso queira colaborar pode fazer o registro em http://tracker.frameworkdemoiselle.gov.br